# Ability to forget the memoized supplier value

Tags: java, multithreading, cache, guava, memoization

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=872) which is asking to provide the ability to forget memoized value on a given supplier.

On top on that I needed another functionality where if during the calculation of expensive value another thread would invalidate the data, the memoisation should retry (guava `LoadableCache` doesn't provide this feature: invalidation during calculation is ignored).

I couldn't wait for this feature so I wrote this myself. First, an interface for forgettable supplier:

```
public interface ForgettableSupplier<T> extends Supplier<T> {
    public void forget();
}
```

Then, a base class, mostly taken from [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mason/archive/2006/09/rechecking_doub.html):

```
public abstract class DoubleCheck<T> extends ReentrantReadWriteLock {

    protected abstract T create();

    protected abstract T retrieve();

    protected abstract boolean invalid(T value);

    public T get() {
        try {
            readLock().lock();
            T value = retrieve();
            while (invalid(value)) { // this spins until no more invalidations are made
                readLock().unlock();
                writeLock().lock();
                value = retrieve();
                try {
                    if (invalid(value)) {
                        value = create();
                    }
                } finally {
                    readLock().lock();
                    writeLock().unlock();
                }
            }
            return value;
        } finally {
            readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the static utility that combines everything together:

```
public class Suppliers {

    private Suppliers() {
    }

    public static <T> ForgettableSupplier<T> memoize(Supplier<T> delegate) {
        return new ForgettableMemoizingSupplier<>(delegate);
    }

    private static final class ForgettableMemoizingSupplier<T> implements ForgettableSupplier<T> {

        private final Supplier<T> delegate;

        private volatile T t;

        private final AtomicBoolean needsToBeForgotten = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        private final DoubleCheck<T> doubleCheck = new DoubleCheck<T>() {
            @Override
            protected T create() {
                needsToBeForgotten.set(false);
                return ForgettableMemoizingSupplier.this.t = delegate.get();
            }

            @Override
            protected T retrieve() {
                return ForgettableMemoizingSupplier.this.t;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean invalid(final T t) {
                return (ForgettableMemoizingSupplier.this.t == null) || needsToBeForgotten.get();
            }
        };

        private ForgettableMemoizingSupplier(final Supplier<T> delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public void forget() {
            needsToBeForgotten.set(true);
        }

        @Override
        public T get() {
            return doubleCheck.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. [Class names should be nouns](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). I'd rename `DoubleCheck` to `DoubleCheckedResource` or something similar.
2. `ForgettableMemoizingSupplier` should not allow `null` suppliers. You should check that and throw a `NullPointerException`.
3. The name of the `invalid` method in the `DoubleCheck` class is ambiguous. Does it invalidate something or does it check that something is valid or not? It seems that the latter is true, so I'd call this `isInvalid` (or `isValid` to eliminate the negation).
4. The `T t` field could be in the `DoubleCheck` anonymous subclass because this is the only class which uses it.
5. Is `DoubleCheck` a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`? Currently it is. I think your clients should not be able to call `getOwner()`, `writeLock()` or `isFair()` on a `DoubleCheck` instance. I'd use composition instead of inheritance here:

   ```
   public abstract class DoubleCheck<T> {

       private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

       private final ReadLock readLock = lock.readLock();

       private final WriteLock writeLock = lock.writeLock();

       ...

   }
   ```

   Check *Effective Java, Second Edition*, *Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*.
6. The `get` method with the `lock()` call in the `finally` block smells a little bit. Are you sure that the object will always be in a consistent state? What happens when `retrieve()`, `create()` or `invalid()` throws an exception? Will  all locks be released properly?

   If I'm right the following is the same but use the [usual `lock(); try { use() } finally { unlock(); }` construction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html):

   ```
   public T get() {
       readLock.lock();
       try {
           final T value = retrieve();
           if (!isInvalid(value)) {
               return value;
           }
       } finally {
           readLock.unlock();
       }

       writeLock.lock();
       try {
           T value = retrieve();
           while (isInvalid(value)) { // this spins until no more invalidations
                                      // are made
               value = retrieve();
               if (isInvalid(value)) {
                   value = create();
               }
           }
           return value;
       } finally {
           writeLock.unlock();
       }
   }
   ```

   (Please note that in the original code between the `readLock.unlock()` and `writeLock.lock()` calls another threads could get the read lock, therefore more than one thread could acquire the write lock at the same time.)
7. If you can ignore the `forget` calls which are parallel with `get` calls it could be more simple:

   ```
   public T get() {
       readLock.lock();
       try {
           final T value = retrieve();
           if (!isInvalid(value)) {
               return value;
           }
       } finally {
           readLock.unlock();
       }

       writeLock.lock();
       try {
           T value = retrieve();
           if (!isInvalid(value)) {
               return value;
           }
           return create();
       } finally {
           writeLock.unlock();
       }
   }
   ```

   (Here `if (isValid(value))` would be more natural than the current `if (!isInvalid(value) ...`.)
8. I'd consider using an `AtomicReference` and a simple `ReentrantLock` too:

   ```
   public final class ForgettableMemoizingSupplier<T> 
           implements ForgettableSupplier<T> {

       private final Supplier<T> delegate;

       private final AtomicReference<T> resourceRef = new AtomicReference<T>(); 

       private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

       public ForgettableMemoizingSupplier(final Supplier<T> delegate) {
           this.delegate = checkNotNull(delegate, "delegate cannot be null");
       }

       @Override
       public void forget() {
           resourceRef.set(null);
       }

       @Override
       public T get() {
           final T resource = resourceRef.get();
           if (resource != null) {
               return resource;
           }
           return getAndSetResource();
       }

       private T getAndSetResource() {
           lock.lock();
           try {
               final T resource = resourceRef.get();
               if (resource != null) {
                   return resource;
               }
               final T newResource = delegate.get();
               resourceRef.set(newResource);
               return newResource;
           } finally {
               lock.unlock();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   (Untested code.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I mostly agree with 1-5 (and have actually done most of these myself independently) but 7-8 are irrelevant because I *need* readers to block until there are no more `forget()` calls and `create()`ing is finished (see the second chapter of my post). Regarding 6 - if I understand correctly, this will make it so two `create()` calls can be running at the same time, right? This might or might not be desirable, I need to think more about this.